# Internet Explorer 11 don't set content-type to multipart/form-data everytime

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, multipartform-data

My app needs to send FormData object to my back-end controller.
So, I created a FormData object in my front-end service and appended some fields.
It works in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE11.
I set `Content-type: undefined` and added a plain text field at the end as suggested in some threads but it doesn't work.

```
    service.SaveMyDatas = function(myDatas) {

        var formData = new FormData();
        var deferred = $q.defer();
          
        formData.append("myField", angular.toJson(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myDatas))));
        
        formData.append('onefield', 'test');
        
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: appServer + '/controllerBackEnd',
            respondType: 'json',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            data : formData
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
// .......
        }, function(response) { 
            deferred.reject(response);
        });
        
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Sometimes it works (1 / 1000 requests, don't why) but most of the time the header `Content-type` is never set to `multipart/form-data`, only `plain/text`.
And if I append a Blob field to the formData IE sets the correct header but the body request is empty.

How can I force IE11 to set the correct header ?

Comment: Have you checked this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43586621/what-is-transformrequest-in-angularjs Try to use transformRequest to send the data?

Comment: Is there any error in console in IE 11? Are you using the FormData polyfill? I found [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593227/empty-values-when-posting-formdata-object-via-fetch-api-in-internet-explorer-11) about using FormData in IE. You could try to add an extra field to the FormData object to see if it works. Besides, this is also like the situation in [this article](https://blog.yorkxin.org/2014/02/06/ajax-with-formdata-is-broken-on-ie10-ie11.html). You can refer to it for more information.